# Reading translations from a plist in Application Support Directory

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, plist

I retrieve translation from a remote server and save this in

> Application\ Support/Translation/Translation.plist

What I basically want to do in my app is use something like

`translate(input: "hello")`

In order to translate hello to the translation that is saved in my plist file. I created a function but I always get nil when reading the contents. Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong?

```
import Foundation

open class Translations {

    static func translate(input: String) -> String {

        var translations: [String: String] = [:] //Translation data
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        let directoryURL = documentsDirectory?.appendingPathComponent("Translation")
        let file = directoryURL?.appendingPathComponent("Translation").appendingPathExtension("plist")

        if let plistXML = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: (file?.absoluteString)!) {
            do {//convert the data to a dictionary and handle errors.
                translations = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistXML, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:String]

            } catch {
                print("Error reading plist: \(error)")
            }
        }

        guard let translation = translations[input] else {
            return input
        }

        return translation
    }
}
```

Comment: `FileManager ` gives the file in the sandbox, try this  to find bundle resource: `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Translation", ofType: "plist")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading from the Documents directory, where as you say earlier in your post your file does not reside in. Instead it resides in the Application Support directory.
Try to make sure you are saving and reading from the same location.

I would also recommend using an extension to `String` to make translating easier, like so:

```
extension String {
    var translated: String {
        return Translation.default?.translate(self) ?? self
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
"SomeText".translated
```

This is how I'd implement translations:

```
    public final class Translation {
  static let `default`: Translation? = Translation()

  let translations: [String: String]

  init?() {
    guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
      return nil
    }
    let translationURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("Translation").appendingPathComponent("Translation").appendingPathExtension("plist")

    do {
      let data = try Data(contentsOfURL: translationURL)
      let propertyList = try PropertyListSerialization(from: data, options: [], format: nil)

      if let list = propertyList as? [String: String] {
        translations = list
      } else {
        return nil
      }
    } catch {
      // Handle error
      return nil
    }
  }

  func translate(_ input: String) -> String {
    guard let translated = translations[input] else {
      return input
    }
    return translated
  }
}
```

This has the advantage that you're not reading the propertyList every time from disk you want to run a translation. Keep in mind that this implementation of mine does not provide any support for refreshing the data once the app is running.

Alternatively you could move the init code to a separate method, and removing the nullability of the init method. Then whenever a new propertyList is downloaded you could simply call -refresh() or whatever you want really.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I think I can work out something out of this